# How to backup Sharepoint databases

Tags: sql-server, backup, sharepoint

I am responsible for backups of normal DBs, but SharePoint is handled by others. Bit worried that we miss something here.

Is SharePoint backup handled completely through some tool in SharePoint, or should I also make regular SQL Backups of the databases outside SharePoint?

Comment: A regular backup should do just fine

Comment: I always do sql backups using ola hallengren's scripts for my sharepoint env

Answer (score -3):

Open SQL Server Management Studio and connect to the database server. Right-click the database that you want to back up, point to Tasks, and then click Back Up.

Comment: Are you sure clicking around is a dependable solution for regular backups?